# how is it call abstract class constructor when i create subclass object?

Tags: java

```
// how is it call abstract class constructor when i create subclass object ?
abstract class D {
    D() {
        System.out.println("called abstract class D constructor");//print
    }
}
public class DemoAbs extends D {
    DemoAbs() {
        System.out.println("called DemoAbs class constructor");
    }
    // how is it call abstract class constructor when i create subclass object ?
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoAbs d=new DemoAbs();
    }
}
```

Comment: inorder to create object, it would call your parent constructor reaching Object's constructor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create an object of subclass, the constructor of subclass will call superclass constructor using super() implicitly. If your parent class constructor accepts parameters, then it is required explicitly to call super(params...);
Otherwise it'll show compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

It's called constructor chaining:

Very first line in a constructor is `super()` unless you explicitly call `this()` OR `this(<with args>)` OR `super(<with args>)`

You should go through:

[Constructor Chaining in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183256/constructor-chaining-in-java)

[Java Constructor Chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640560/java-constructor-chaining)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a constructor is called, it first calls `super()`, which means that the constructor of the superclass is called to initialize all variables in the superclass, after which the rest of the constructor of the subclass is executed.